# Delete multiple rows using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server

I am trying to delete rows from my sql database using `checkbox`. This is working fine as long as there is only one `checkbox` marked. But I also want it to be possible to delete multiple rows. I have seen many example, but I cant get it to work. Hope anyone here can help me.

So first the result.php file (here is all the rows / table created):

```
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' class='toedit' value='" . $row[0] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

This file is included in my main html (main.html) file, here is the Jquery as well.

Jquery sending chechbox variables to delete.php file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".deletelogg").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "php/delete.php",
                data:  {id:$('.toedit:checked:first').val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);
                }
            });
   });
   </script>
```

Last in my delete.php file:

```
include 'connect-database.php';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id']); $i++) {
    if ($_POST['id'][$i] != "") {
        echo $_POST['id'] ;
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Logg Where LoggID LIKE '".$_POST['id']."'";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
        if ($stmt == false) {
            die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
    }  
}
```

I was trying to make an array containing all `id` from the `checkbox`, but it didn't work.. any help pleas?

Comment: You can't do that quite like that. You would need to parse your values in your query if you are passing multiple values. Also, you need to parameterize your queries. What you have here is a textbook example of sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1y4zy5mn/

You should iterate over your checkboxes and collect the values. Given the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="toedit" value="1" />
        </td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="toedit" value="2" />
        </td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="toedit" value="3" />
        </td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" class="toedit" value="4" />
        </td>
        <td>Blue</td>
        <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="deletelogg">Delete</button>
<p></p>
```

Your JQuery will need to do a little more work. This should work for 1 or many:

```
$(".deletelogg").on('click', function () {
    var ids = [];
    $(".toedit").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            ids.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    if (ids.length) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "php/delete.php",
            data: {
                id: ids
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("p").text(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please select items.");
    }
});
```

With this, you can switch to a `foreach()` loop too:

```
include 'connect-database.php';

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
    echo $id;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Logg Where LoggID = $id";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if ($stmt == false) {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this way: first make a "checkAll" checkbox, and when is checked, check all your check-boxes. Then at the end of your form, put the "delete" button. When this one is pressed, all the checked check-boxes are deleted. I think this works even for some of the check-boxes (if you only check some of them, not all of them).

```
<div id="content"></div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">

//get all the rows from db here, or make them manually
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row->id;?>">
//...
```

Then, with this piece of js code, you can check them all, or some of them, and "send" them to a server-side script which will grab them, and delete them from the db.

```
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var param = "";
var params = [];
for (var counter=0; counter < checkBoxes.length; counter++) {
    if (checkBoxes[counter].type.toUpperCase()=='CHECKBOX' && checkBoxes[counter].checked == true) {
        param += checkBoxes[counter].value+' ';
        params = param;
    }
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/server/side/script",
    data: { params:params },
    success: function(resp){
        $('#content').html(resp);
    }
});
```

And for checking them all:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but is a point to start. Also, don't forget to secure your app.